# how to disable macOS prompt menu animation（or add speed）?

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, osx-leopard, macos-sierra, macos-catalina

In most apps macOS, there is a prompt menu, e.g. when I saving files by a TextEdit, this prompt will show, and there is an animation, I don't want the animation, since its somehow slow, how to disable or add speed of this?  I've searched, that I can check "reduce motion" in "accessibility", but this will eliminate all animations such as mission control animation(four-finger swipe up), and I don't want to disable mission control animation, how to achieve this?

[the prompt menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwYwJ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI element you're calling a "prompt menu" is officially known as a "sheet" in macOS UI terminology. Sheets are a kind of dialog box that are drawn as emerging from a window's title bar. The "Save" sheet is one of the most common sheets users see.

From Super User's sister site apple.stackexchange.com, a.k.a "AskDifferent":

How to turn off all animations on OS X
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14001/how-to-turn-off-all-animations-on-os-x

```
# showing and hiding sheets, resizing preference windows, zooming windows
# float 0 doesn't work
defaults write -g NSWindowResizeTime -float 0.001
```

I tried it in macOS Mojave 10.14.6 and it works. Apps that are already running will not get the change until you quit and re-launch them.

Comment: you saved my life

Comment: You have to wonder if the devs responsible for these animations actually use macOS. While working, I always have tons of temp text files open with notes and clipboard contents, etc., in them. When it comes time to close them all, the animations make it painful. Thanks for this question and answer!